# nested_form - edit action doesn't show nested elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I have a [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) where nested elements are dynamically added and removed in a form, using Javascript.

I've got this whole piece working for the `new` action - elements add and destroy, and everything saves as it should.

When accessing the `edit` action, I get the correct parent element but the child elements **do not display** - instead, the `edit` view teases me with a lingering (and unhelpful) 'Add Option' button.

Where might I be going wrong here?

Comment: It is very hard to help without any source. Are there no children? what does 'add option' mean? Is this what you are adding? options? Please show the view and the controller code that gathers the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue (I seriously lost some hair on it). I was glad to find this question, no one else seemed to have it. My solution was "trivial": I upgraded from Rails 3.0.0 to 3.0.6 (3.0.7 brought up another issue) on my Windows Box.

I did not investigate any further, 'coz it works now. I did not change any single line of code. Perhaps this is a valid fix for ya, too.

Plz, let me know...

Regards, Dirk

Answer (score 2):

try the gem cocoon it's really handy and takes care of the nested forms javascript for you!!

Here's the link http://www.dixis.com/?p=454&lang=nl

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion. I am already significantly time-invested in `nested_form` so a solution to this specific problem would be more helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same problem, and discovered that it was down to the "fields_for" block that created the nested elements. For instance, I had:

```
<%= nested_form_for(@recipe) do |f| %>

  # Stuff for parent...

  <% f.fields_for :recipe_ingredients do |ingredient_form| %>
    # Stuff for nested form...
  <% end %>
  # etc.
```

This line needed to be a `<%=` block, not a `<%` block as above, i.e.

```
<%= nested_form_for(@recipe) do |f| %>

  # Stuff for parent...

  # The following line has changed
  <%= f.fields_for :recipe_ingredients do |ingredient_form| %>
    # Stuff for nested form...
  <% end %>
  # etc.
```

That was all it needed to print out existing nested attributes on the edit form.

Answer (score 0):

Check out your form for editing the resource.
Try to use instance variable in parent form, like this:

```
<%= form_for @parent_resource do |form| %>
   ... some field ...
<%= form.fields_for :children_resources do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```